# Background of Text with spacing

Tags: css, text, colors, background, format

please have a look at the attached picture... For a wordpress site I need to enter a custom CSS. I have a slogan or company name which needs to have a background color. But when the site is responsive and the text is splitted into another row, I need a space.

But when I search through google I only get results for changing the complete background of the text field.

```
.ueberschrift {
     background-color: #FF00E9;
     padding: 8px;
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Regards
Markus

[My results...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FXLr.jpg)

Comment: Could you post some more code, or post it on jfiddle or codepen, so we can help you

Comment: Hey Coja, cause i use wpbakery at wordpress for theme design, I have only the possibility to enter a individual css to that specific page. In wpbakery I created a textfield and gave it a CSS class. Than I tryed to specify the formating with the custom css with refer to the css class I created.

Comment: Gotcha, well, what i would try, is look in the css where the background color, that grey-ish is, and then put padding on that, that should be some div maybe or something. And if that doesnt have a class, just add it via custom css and put a padding on it. Hope this helps :_)

Comment: Coja, can you work with this code?
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FF00E9;
  padding: 8px;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #FF00E9;
  padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 >My First CSS Example</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>

Here I hace the same result which I dont want...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y0zk1gwm/

Comment: Well, look at this. [It look good for me](https://imgur.com/a/W8hf8Se). Now, maybe the problem is the size of your monitor/laptop maaaybe

Answer (score 0):

try changing the css code to:

```
.ueberschrift p {
     background-color: #FF00E9;
     padding: 8px;
}
```

i added a "p" after ".ueberschrift" class which should only select the text.

Comment: Hey eeeltie, I tryed too add the "p" but than the whole colored background disappears.
I can not add a picture to this comment function at stackoverflow. So I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need a margint(white space) between Schwere and disthymische.......
To achive this you must think first of all to put the all sentence in 2 containters.
for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="ueberschrift">
 <span>Schwere</span>
 <span>disthymische.......</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ueberschrift span {
 background-color: #FF00E9;
 padding: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

In this way you will set a margin bottom between 2 spans, when you at a small resolution.